# How to redirect my Facebook app to App Center?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I have a Facebook app (Native iOS App and Native Android App using Facebook). I want the following to happen:

1. I search for my app on Facebook.com
2. I click on the app in search result and get redirected to App Center http://www.facebook.com/appcenter/my_app (so that the user get info about my app)

I can't get this working, I always get redirected to the "Canvas URL" I enter under "App on Facebook" in settings. If I instead disable "App on Facebook" in settings and search for my app and click it I get error message saying:

```
To fix this error, please set your Canvas URL and/or Secure Canvas URL in the "App on Facebook" section of your app's settings.
```

How can I solve this issue? What am I missing? I really want to use the App Center. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I get this exact same problem. I have multiple apps and those with a canvas URL specified redirect to the canvas URL, while those without one correctly redirect to the app center. I wonder if this is a bug with submitting app details while having a canvas URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked on my apps today (10/22/2012) and the problem appears to have been fixed by FB. When I search my apps, they all correctly redirect to the App Center when I search for them, regardless of whether a canvas URL is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Have you submitted the app details (App Details link just below Settings)?

Comment: Yes I have entered all that details and submitted my app. Status says: "App Detail Page Status: Live Your app detail page is now live and will appear in Search."